# Address already in use - Amazon AWS

Tags: apache-2.2, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, httpd

I've run into a really weird issue. I was debugging a server 500 error script on our EC2 instance and found that we didn't have ioncube loaders installed. So I went to go install them and I created a new file at `/etc/php.d/zend.ini` and initially I inserted the value of `extension=/usr/local/ioncube/ioncube_loader_lin_5.3.so` and restarted httpd at which point it told me:

```
The ionCube Loader is a Zend-Engine extension and not a module
Please specify the Loader using 'zend_extension' in php.ini
PHP Fatal error:  Unable to start ionCube Loader module in Unknown on line 0
```

So I changed the contents of zend.ini to zend_extension=/usr/...etc. Now when I attempt to restart httpd I get this error:

```
Starting httpd: (98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
(98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
Unable to open logs
```

I can't even run `/etc/init.d/httpd stop` without it erroring. I've since removed zend.ini to see if that's what caused it and it doesn't seem to be.

Any ideas?

Comment: Check to see what's listening on port 80. Make sure port 80 is clear. Then start apache.

Comment: Did you restart using sudo?

Answer (score 4):

If there isn't anything listening on port 80 as per the suggestion from David Schwartz, the problem is most likely that you have two `Listen 80` directives in your Apache config.  They may not be near each other or even in the same file.

Try `grep -r Listen /etc/httpd` to find them and remove one of them.

Answer (score 0):

Zend-server should  be remove

```
yum zend-server remove
```

Remove

```
rm -f /var/lock/subsys/httpd
```

close process httpd

```
ipcs -s | grep apache |  perl -e 'while (<STDIN>) { @a=split(/\s+/); print `ipcrm sem $a[1]`}'
```

See the status apache

```
/etc/init.d/httpd status
```

Then start apache

```
/etc/init.d/httpd start
```